# Approximation in $L^p$ spaces

Tags: lp-spaces

Let $X$ denotes the span {$x^n:n \ge1 $}. Is it true that $X $ is dense in $L^1([0,1])?.$
I showed that $X$ is dense in the space of continuous functions that vanishes at zero. I also know space of continuous functions with compact support is dense in $L^p$ space.
I guess it not true but my friend told me it is true.
Anybody's help would be appreciated

Comment: Use the Stone-Weierstrass approximation theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: given any continuous function on $[0,1]$, you can approximate it in the $L^1$ norm by continuous functions that vanish at $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I am still confused could you please elaborate little bit..

Comment: Given any $f \in L^1$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there is a continuous function $g$ on $[0,1]$ with $\|f - g\|_1 < \epsilon/3$.  There is a continuous function $h$ on $[0,1]$ with $h(0) = 0$ and $\|g - h\|_1 < \epsilon/3$.
There is $p \in X$ with $\|h - p\|_1 \le \|h - p\|_\infty < \epsilon/3$...

Comment: By the help of your hint, i also did exactly same, thank you it helped me to verify my work...